# Safe alternatives to PHP Globals (Good Coding Practices)

Tags: php, performance, security

For years I have used `global $var,$var2,...,$varn` for methods in my application. I've used them for two main implementations:

Getting an already set class (such as DB connection), and passing info to functions that display to page.

**Example:**

```
$output['header']['log_out'] = "Log Out";
function showPage(){
     global $db, $output;
     $db = ( isset( $db ) ) ? $db : new Database();
     $output['header']['title'] = $db->getConfig( 'siteTitle' );
     require( 'myHTMLPage.html' );
     exit();
}
```

There are, however, performance and security ramifications of doing it like this.

What alternative practice can I use that will maintain my functionality but improve design, performance, and/or security?

*This is the first question I've ever asked on SO, so if you need clarifications please comment!*

Comment: PHP does not have real global variables. And the security myths stem from confusion with `register_globals`. The `$db` global is a very common practice. Your `$output` variable might be less advisable (can't tell from a short snippet). Generally: sharing access with the global scope is practicable, while using it for signaling should not be prevalent.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Output is probably the best example of a needed global, and also the least dangerous in my case. The output array ONLY contains things to be output directly to the browser. So the case is almost always benign, unless a user can maliciously inject code into it which exposes credentials. Which, if that's possible with register_globals off, please let me know!

Comment: If function needs a variable, you pass it to it. `$foo = some_function($connectionObject);`

Comment: Why can't you just pass the variable to the function, by reference if necessary?

Comment: @BenBrocka there can be many reasons. For example OP might be implementing an interface where the method signature does not allow parameters.

Comment: go for ur 2nd alternative if u do not want to use OOP it is simple and useful.
else OOP is the best thing

Comment: @tereško Huh?  I am not hanging on here.

Comment: @ChaitanyaChandurkar I would unless the whole core would be written in procedural, and we aren't experienced in OOP to actually gain anything of it. "Don't use it, unless you need it"

Comment: ok then 2nd alternative is best u can do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The alternative is called *dependency injection*. In a nutshell it means that you pass the data a function/class/object requires as parameters.

```
function showPage(Database $db, array &$output) {
    ...
}


$output['header']['log_out'] = "Log Out";
$db = new Database;

showPage($db, $output);
```

This is better for a number of reasons:

- localizing/encapsulating/namespacing functionality (the function body has no implicit dependencies to the outside world anymore and vice versa, you can now rewrite either part without needing to rewrite the other as long as the function call doesn't change)
- allows unit testing, since you can test functions in isolation without needing to setup a specific outside world
- it's clear what a function is going to do to your code just by looking at the signature

Comment: The issue for me passing these in as parameters, though, is that with any given function I may have potentially dozens of already allocated resources which I may need to pass through, in addition to the parameters the function already requires. Then, every-time I need to add a new resource, I'll have to revisit all these functions to make the appropriate change to the parameters.

Comment: I think that goes back to a larger issue of properly structuring your application. If you need to keep passing in more resources, that means the functionality of those functions changes (otherwise they wouldn't need the resources, right?), which means your functions probably have badly defined responsibilities. Assuming there is a legitimate need though, you could pass a general object or array that contains all needed resources (recommended anyway if you need to pass more than a handful of parameters). An MVC controller object approach can also help.

Answer (score 16):

> 1. Globals. Works like a charm. Globals are hated thus my thoughts of not using it.

Well, globals are not just hated. They are hated for a reason. If you didn't run so far into the problems globals cause, fine. There is no need for you to refactor your code.

> 2. Define a constant in my config.php file.

This is actually just like a global, but with another name. You would spare the `$` as well and to use the `global` at the beginning of functions. Wordpress did this for their configuration, I'd say this is more bad than using global variables. It makes it much more complicated to introduce seams. Also you can not assign an object to a constant.

> 3. Include the config file in the function.

I'd consider this as overhead. You segmentize the codebase for not much gain. The "global" here will become the name of the file you inlcude btw..

---

Taken these three thoughts of you and my comments to them into account I'd say: Unless you run into actual issues with some global variables, you can stick to them. Global then work as your service locator (configuration, database). Others do much more to create the same.

If you run into problems (e.g. you probably want to develop test-driven), I suggest you start with putting one part after the other under test and then you learn how to avoid the globals.

### Dependency Injection

As inside comments it became clear you're looking for dependency injection, and if you can not edit the function parameter definition, you can - if you use objects - inject dependencies via the constructor or by using so called *setter methods*. In the following example code I'll do both which is for demonstration purposes only as you might have guessed, it's not useful to use both at once:

Let's say the configuration array is the dependency we would like to inject. Let's call it `config` and name the variable `$config`. As it is an array, we can type-hint it as `array`. first of all define the configuration in a include file maybe, you could also use [`parse_ini_file`](http://de.php.net/parse_ini_file) if you prefer the ini-file format. I think it's even faster.

`config.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * configuration file
 */
return array(
    'db_user' => 'root',
    'db_pass' => '',
);
```

That file then can just be required inside your application where-ever you want to:

```
$config = require('/path/to/config.php');
```

So it can be easily turned into an array variable somewhere in your code. Nothing spectacular so far and totally unrelated to dependency injection. Let's see an exemplary database class which needs to have the configuration here, it needs to have the username and the password otherwise it can't connect let's say:

```
class DBLayer
{
    private $config;

    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $this->setConfig($config);
    }

    public function setConfig(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function oneICanNotChange($paramFixed1, $paramFixed2)
    {
        $user = $this->config['db_user'];
        $password = $this->config['db_pass'];
        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new DBLayerException('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

        ...
}
```

This example is a bit rough, but it has the two examples of dependency injection. First via the constructor:

```
public function __construct(array $config)
```

This one is very common, all dependencies the class needs to do it's work are injection at creation time. This also ensures that when any other method of that object is called, the object will be in a pre-determinable state - which is somewhat important for a system.

The second example is to have a public *setter method*:

```
public function setConfig(array $config)
```

This allows to add the dependency later, but some methods might need to check for things being available prior doing their job. E.g. if you could create the `DBLayer` object without providing configuration, the `oneICanNotChange` method could be called without that object having configuration and should had to deal with that (which is not shown in this example).

### Service Locator

As you need to probably integrate code on the fly and you want your new code to be put under test with dependency injection and all that what's making our live easier, you might need to put this together with your ancient / legacy code. I think that part is tough. Dependency injection on it's own is pretty easy, but putting this together with old code is not that straight forward.

What I can suggest here is that you make one global variable that is the so called *service locator*. It contains a central point to fetch objects (or even arrays like your `$config`) from. It can be used then and the contract is that single variable name. So to remove globals we make use of a global variable. Sounds a bit counter-productive and it even is if your new code uses it too much as well. However, you need some tool to bring old and new together. So here is the most bare PHP service locator implementation I could imagine so far.

It consists of one `Services` object that offers all of your services, like the `config` from above. Because when a PHP script starts, we yet do not know if a service at all is needed (e.g. we might not run any database query, so we don't need to instantiate the database), it offers some lazy initialization feature as well. This is done by using factory-scripts that are just PHP files that setup the service and return it.

A first example: Let's say the function `oneICanNotChange` would not have been part of an object but just a simple function in the global namespace. We would not have been able to inject `config` dependency. This is where the `Services` Service Locator object comes in:

```
$services = new Services(array(
    'config' => '/path/to/config.php',
));

...

function oneICanNotChange($paramFixed1, $paramFixed2)
{
    global $services;
    $user = $services['config']['db_user'];
    $password = $services['config']['db_pass'];

    ...
```

As the example already shows, the `Services` object does map the string `'config'` to the path of the PHP file that defines the `$config` array: `/path/to/config.php`. It uses the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/ArrayAccess) interface than to expose that service inside the `oneICanNotChange` function.

I suggest the `ArrayAccess` interface here, because it's well defined and it shows that we have some dynamic character here. On the other hand it allows us the lazy initialization:

```
class Services implements ArrayAccess
{
    private $config;
    private $services;

    public function __construct(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }
    ...
    public function offsetGet($name)
    {
        return @$this->services[$name] ?
            : $this->services[$name] = require($this->config[$name]);
   }
   ...
}
```

This exemplary stub just requires the factory scripts if it has not done so far, otherwise will return the scripts return value, like an array, an object or even a string (but not `NULL` which makes sense).

I hope these examples are helpful and show that not much code is needed to gain more flexibility here and punching globals out of your code. But you should be clear, that the service locator introduces global state to your code. The benefit is just, that it's easier to de-couple this from concrete variable names and to provide a bit more flexibility. Maybe you're able to divide the objects you use in your code into certain groups, of which only some need to become available via the service-locator and you can keep the code small that depends on the locator.

Comment: Oh @hakre, I wanted to upvote so badly until I got to the end ... Yes, it's probably okay to leave the globals in: the code will still work. But the OP is asking for the preferred solution, and the preferred solution is Dependency Injection. Granted it's not a Computer Science 101 solution and it requires a fair amount of experience, but it's still the optimal solution.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned Dependency Injection as an alternative, but I'm not confident with the detail of information given here (*"The variable can't be passed via the the parameter since I don't have access to it from there and it shouldn't be needed as well."*) - so I even don't know if injection via the constructor would work. And if not, this is close to a global variable again. So I left that part out because this can turn into a non-productive discussion until OP becomes more clear what he wants and what he is willing to do for that.

Comment: Wow.  I have never come across the term "dependency injection".  (I'm a sysadmin first, untrained programmer way later).  But it turns out I've been using dependency injection in my own PHP projects since about 1999.  @rdlowrey - thanks for teaching me a "new" term.  :-D

Comment: I added a Dependency Injection and a Service Locator example in the hope this is useful. I tried to keep things light here so you can adopt.

Comment: You would also need to implement three additional methods to use the ArrayAccess interface.

Comment: @josmith: Sure, that's what the `...` are for in the example, that was by intend to not make the example so large. I probably should compile a gist and link it.

Answer (score 7):

> There are, however, performance and security ramifications of doing it like this.

To tell you truth, there are no performance nor security ramifications. Using globals is a matter of cleaner code, and nothing more. (Well, okay, as long as you're not passing variables of tens of megabytes in size)

So, you have to think first, will alternatives make *cleaner* code for you, or not.

In matters of cleaner code, I'd be in fear if I see a db connection in the function called showPage.

Comment: Thank you for the input! I'm glad for the reassurance that this isn't a glaring security problem. People have told me it is, but I haven't been offered an explanation - thus leading to my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

One option that some people may frown upon is to create a [singleton](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php) object responsible for holding the application state.  When you want to access some shared "global" object you could make a call like:  `State::get()->db->query();` or `$db = State::get()->db;`.

I see this method as a reasonable approach as it saves having to pass around a bunch of objects all over the place.

EDIT:

Using this approach can help simplify the organization and readability of your application.   For example, your state class could call the proper methods to initialize your database object and decouple its initialization from your showPage function.

```
class State {
    private static $instance;
    private $_db;

    public function getDB() {
        if(!isset($this->_db)){ 
            // or call your database initialization code or set this in some sort of
            // initialization method for your whole application
            $this->_db = new Database();
        }
        return $this->_db;
    }

    public function getOutput() {
        // do your output stuff here similar to the db
    }

    private function __construct() { }

    public static function get() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $className = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new State;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __clone() {
        trigger_error('Clone is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    public function __wakeup() {
        trigger_error('Unserializing is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

and your show page function could be something like this:

```
function showPage(){
     $output = State::get()->getOutput();
     $output['header']['title'] = State::get()->getDB()->getConfig( 'siteTitle' );
     require( 'myHTMLPage.html' );
     exit();
}
```

An alternative to using a singleton object is to pass the state object to your various functions, this allows you to have alternative "states" if your application gets complicated and you will only need to pass around a single state object.

```
function showPage($state){
     $output = $state->getOutput();
     $output['header']['title'] = $state->getDB()->getConfig( 'siteTitle' );
     require( 'myHTMLPage.html' );
     exit();
}

$state = new State; // you'll have to remove all the singleton code in my example.
showPage($state);
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Would you mind briefly clarifying some of the benefits over my current approach?

Comment: Thank you! I am going to use this approach in conjunction with @Col. Shrapnel 's suggestion. I'll probably keep passing $output as global, but the singleton will help reduce code from instantiating multiple DB connections.

Comment: Instead of triggering an error in `public` `__clone` & `__wakeup`, define them as `final private`

Comment: Oh, and [deceze's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290993/safe-alternatives-to-php-globals-good-coding-practices/7291043#7291043) is the better one. Singleton's should only be used when there can ever only be a single instance of the object, because of Business rules or Technical limitations (There can only be one active sessions for example). In all other cases, singletons will cause more problems than they solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
function showPage(&$output, $db = null){
     $db = is_null( $db )  ? new Database() : $db;
     $output['header']['title'] = $db->getConfig( 'siteTitle' );
     require( 'myHTMLPage.html' );
     exit();
}
```

and

```
$output['header']['log_out'] = "Log Out";
showPage($output);

 $db =new Database();
showPage($output,$db);
```

Comment: I'm familiar with parameters but I feel like that's a sloppy implementation. Keep in mind that this has to apply to many many functions, and there content that is handled in them is often dynamic.

Comment: @ShaneC, this is the proper pattern to follow. If dependency injection gets burdensome because you need to pass in to many arguments, it is a tell-tale sign of wrong architecture on a larger scale.

Comment: @Jacco Well the issue, truthfully, isn't so much I need to pass so many parameters - I'm using an MVC with class autoloading - but if I decide to incorporate a new global resource I feel like adding an extra parameter is burdensome. Since PHP doesn't really support class polymorphism I feel getting into that business is dicey. My plan is to use my current method, sans global DB in favor of a singleton (to maintain one active connection, unless overridden). If you see an error with this plan please let me know!!

Answer (score 0):

Start designing your code in OOP, then you can pass config to the constructor. You could also encapsulate all your functions into a class.

```
<?php 
class functions{
    function __construct($config){
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    function a(){
        //$this->config is available in all these functions/methods
    }

    function b(){
        $doseSomething = $this->config['someKey'];
    }

    ...

}


$config = array(
'someKey'=>'somevalue'
);

$functions = new functions($config);

$result = $functions->a();
?>
```

Or if you cant refactor the script, loop through the config array and define constants.

```
foreach($config as $key=>$value){
    define($key,$value);
}
```

Comment: I gave the three alternatives for a reason. Rewriting the core is not an option.

Comment: This is not rewriting. Its just a new class that you can add

Comment: That's not really any better than passing the $config to the function directly, or using a global. You're just exchanging one syntax for another... And what you wrote isn't exactly OOP either, it looks more like a library of independent functions wrapped in a class. - Just using a class doesn't make the code OOP. The "design" has to be OOP, not the syntax.

Comment: @Atli yeah i understand that, tho is there a better answer when the OP does not want to refactor his code?

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone Yes. It's all procedural, even what you wrote (despite your use of a the class syntax), so you may as well remove the class definition, stick with functions and just import $config using the "global" keyword. That's roughly equivalent to what you did. - Although, of the options available to non-OOP code, globals would be third on my list. First would be passing it as a parameter (which the OP ruled out), and second would be using constants. - It's all globally available info anyways, so you may as well do it properly.