# What to use instead of a global variable?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Safe alternatives to PHP Globals (Good Coding Practices)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290993/safe-alternatives-to-php-globals-good-coding-practices)

I have a variable I need in a function. It's stored in config.php in a $config array. The variable can't be passed via the the parameter since I don't have access to it from there and it shouldn't be needed as well.

So I believe I have three alternatives (procedural only) here:

1. Globals. Works like a charm. Globals are hated thus my thoughts of not using it.
2. Define a constant in my config.php file.
3. Include the config file in the function.

What alternative should I go for?

Comment: @John, i could ask you the same , only in form "reasons for revenge downvoting"? .. especially since i was busy looking for duplicate of this question and did not even bother to downvote.

Comment: @tereško the duplicate discusses OOP, but this question is about procedural.

Comment: Good job, it's not even a duplicate.