# Straight forward example of Dependency Injection Container in PHP

Tags: php, dependency-injection

Can somebody throw some light with a basic working example for a Dependency Injection Container (DIC) in PHP?

I know this is a sort of vague question, I have been going through some examples especially from Fabian Potencier where he explained what is DI in PHP in a good way with a working example.

Apart from Fabian I went through some more articles, but I am in search of a working example for DIC, so that guys like me will get a better understanding with a simple working example.

May be a small explanation why we need to use DIC would also be helpful, like in which context will it come in handy and so.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know if you read that article:
http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/07/07/dependency-injection-moving-from-basics-to-container/

but it helped me to understand the advantages of DI

Richard Miller had also a good presentation about why to use DI:
https://speakerdeck.com/u/richardmiller/p/dependency-injection-and-the-symfony2-service-container

It gives just dummy code examples, but you surely will recognize some real world issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you had not read so far this article, I can highly suggest it:

- [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

It's not too long but not too short either. Per the Container, it talks about PicoContainer which was originally written in Java. A PHP variant of it exists:

- http://svn.picocontainer.codehaus.org/browse/picocontainer/php/picocontainer/trunk/container

Documentation specific to PicoContainer is:

- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/PICO/Home
- and here: http://picocontainer.codehaus.org/

I described a *very rudimentary* Service Locator for PHP in some other answer ([Safe alternatives to PHP Globals (Good Coding Practices)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10963049/367456)), however it's more a lazy initialization pattern I'd say. But you asked for much simplified things, so probably that is of use.