# Echo sqrt and pow

Tags: php, html

I made this task for school but I can't get further.
It won't get the result I want it to have.
It must be the solution for the sqrt and pow in a function.
Can you tell me what I did wrong?

```
body {
  font-family: Cambria;
  background-color: #9A9FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

php:

```
<?php 
    // Declareren
    $getal=5 ;
    $hoeveelKwadraad=2 ;

    // Functies
    function kwadraad($hoeveelKwadraad) {
        echo ''. pow($getal, $hoeveelKwadraad);
    }
    function wortel() { echo ''. sqrt($getal); }
    if (is_numeric($getal)) {
        echo 'Het getal '. $getal . ' in het kwadraad '. $hoeveelKwadraad . ' = ' . kwadraad($hoeveelKwadraad) . '<br><br>';
        echo 'De wortel van het getal '. $getal . ' = ' . wortel(); 
    } else { 
        echo 'Je getal is geen getal maar iets anders, voeg een getal in!'; 
    }
?>
```

**EDIT:**

```
body{
    font-family:Cambria;
    background-color:#9A9FFF;
    font-size:20px;
}
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;   
}
```

php:

```
<?php

// Decladeren
$getal = 5;
$hoeveelKwadraad = 2;

// Functies
function kwadraad($hoeveelKwadraad, $getal){
    echo ''. pow($getal, $hoeveelKwadraad);
}
function wortel($getal){
    echo ''. sqrt($getal);
}

if(is_numeric($getal)){
    echo 'Het getal '. $getal . ' in het kwadraad '. $hoeveelKwadraad . ' = ' . kwadraad($hoeveelKwadraad, $getal) . '<br><br>';
    echo 'De wortel van het getal '. $getal . ' = ' . wortel($getal);
}
else{
    echo 'Je getal is geen getal maar iets anders, voeg een getal in!';
}

?>
```

**Result i get:**

[image]

The answer must be at the end of the sentence, now it is at the beginning.

Comment: If you want to use the result of your function in string concatenation (echo it out...), you should return it instead of echoing it in the function itself. And you need to send all variables you use in your function to your function as parameters, also see http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php.

Comment: You have to declare `$getal` as a `global` (`global $getal;`) at the beginning of your functions. Or pass the $getal value as an argument to your functions

Comment: You have to read about [variabe scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php): inside a function `$getal` is not the global `$getal`: you have to call it in this way: `function functionname() { global $getal; echo sqrt($getal); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is one of variable scope.

`$getal` is not visible inside a function by default, so the Best solution is to pass that variable as a parameter to your functions. *Dont use global*

Also you are `echo`'ing the results of your calculations directly writing to the output buffer, instead use return.

```
<?php

// Decladeren

$getal = 5;
$hoeveelKwadraad = 2;

// Functies

function kwadraad($hoeveelKwadraad, $getal){
    // also return the value, dont directly echo it
    return pow($getal, $hoeveelKwadraad);
}
function wortel($getal){
    // also return the value, dont directly echo it
    return sqrt($getal);
}

if(is_numeric($getal)){
    echo 'Het getal '. $getal . ' in het kwadraad '. $hoeveelKwadraad . ' = ' . kwadraad($hoeveelKwadraad, $getal) . '<br><br>';
    echo 'De wortel van het getal '. $getal . ' = ' . wortel($getal);
}
else{
    echo 'Je getal is geen getal maar iets anders, voeg een getal in!';
}

?>
```

Comment: Why don't you recommend global? In a lot of cases u use multiple values, you recommend passing them all? it only complicates the the code in my opinion so would really like to know why not to use global.

Comment: If you pass it as a parameter, there is absolutely no confusion about what is required in the function, it becomes self documented.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290993/safe-alternatives-to-php-globals-good-coding-practices

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I Have always used global before but mainly because i program in C# and to keep coding as similar as possible and to keep function calls as short as possible, but i see that in php it is not the best practice.

Comment: Where do you use global most for?

Comment: I haven't used it once, because we didn't learned it at school.